# How to present two different ViewControllers from AppDelegate based on two conditions in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to present two ViewControllers from AppDelegate  when the app is resumed from minimising.
I have used `applicationWillEnterForeground:` function to present the ViewControllers. But when I run the app with the below code, it crashes and shows an error as: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <ViewController: 0x1566a420>.'` And I have used storyBoards to present ViewControllers not nib Files.
Please help me with this issue as where I am going wrong. I have been struggling with this since a week.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(ConditionOne)
    {
         [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self getMyFilesActivityView] animated:YES completion:nil];
         [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if(ConditionTwo)
    {
         [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self getPasswordActivityView] animated:YES completion:nil];
         [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
-(MyFilesViewController *)getMyFilesActivityView
{
    if(self.myFiles== nil)
    {
        self.myFiles = [[MyFilesViewController alloc]init];
        myFiles = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyFilesID"];
    }
    return self.myFiles;
}
-(PasswordEnterViewController *)getPasswordActivityView
{
    if(self.passwordEnter== nil)
    {
        self.passwordEnter = [[PasswordEnterViewController alloc]init];
        passwordEnter = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PasswordEnterID"];
    }
    return self.passwordEnter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong here.

First, when you run this code:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self getMyFilesActivityView] animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It will first present the view controller and then dismiss it directly after, which is not what you want. Do you want to dismiss the old view controller before showing the other one? Then you should do this instead:

```
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[self getViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Also, there is something very wrong with your getters:

```
    self.passwordEnter = [[PasswordEnterViewController alloc]init];
    passwordEnter = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PasswordEnterID"];
```

The first row allocates a PasswordEnterViewController, and the second row does the same thing. The first row will do nothing in this case (if self.passwordEnter and passwordEnter is even the same variable, it's very unclear.)

This is how your setters should look:

```
- (PasswordEnterViewController *)passwordEnter
{
    if(_passwordEnter == nil)
    {
        self.passwordEnter = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PasswordEnterID"];
    }
    return _passwordEnter;
}
```

And your property for passwordEnter should look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *passwordEnter;
```

Also, remove any `@synthesize` call you might be doing, since you seem to be overriding the automatic synthesizer, which makes your code hard to follow.

When your setter and property looks like above, you can simply use the following code to present it:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.passwordEnter animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I tried the same way as what you said, but its still crashing with the  same error.

Comment: Then either your storyboard identifier is wrong, or you implemented the getters wrong. In either case, the getters must be returning nil. Try to put a breakpoint there and find out why

Comment: I have declared the storyboard also as a property. So is that affecting the code??

Comment: Yes, that could be what's wrong. Do not declare the storyboard! self.storyboard is a view controller property that gets the storyboard that the view controller running the code was loaded from. Instead you could use [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName"] instantiateView... etc

Comment: If I dont declare storyboard, then its showing error as "No known class for selector instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Comment: You must write [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName"] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];